# Seeking example of asynchronous methods in Java standard library

Tags: java, asynchronous

I'd like to find an example in the Java standard libraries of a method that takes a callback as an argument, returns immediately, and invokes the callback when it has completed its task. For example, you could imagine a method to get user input from the keyboard that returns immediately but invokes the callback once the input has been entered.

Next best would be a method that calls a listener when it has completed its task. An example from the Android SDK would be [`SoundPool.load()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/SoundPool#load(android.content.Context,%20int,%20int)) and [`SoundPool.setOnLoadCompleteListener()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/SoundPool#setOnLoadCompleteListener(android.media.SoundPool.OnLoadCompleteListener)).

I don't consider Swing methods like `addActionListener()` to be examples, since the purpose of the method is to add the listener. The triggering event is entirely separate.

My motivation is preparing a lecture on Java I/O and wanting to contrast methods that (1) block, (2) return immediately with or without data, or (3) use callbacks.

Comment: Take a look at the [asynchronous channel](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/channels/AsynchronousChannel.html) implementations of Java NIO.

Comment: Thanks, @Slaw. I found [AsynchronousFileChannel.write](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/channels/AsynchronousFileChannel.html), which is just the sort of thing I was hoping for. Do you want to post an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One group of examples you're looking for is the Java NIO [AynchronousChannel](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/channels/AsynchronousChannel.html) implementations. For instance:

- [AsynchronousFileChannel#lock(A, CompletionHandler)](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/channels/AsynchronousFileChannel.html#lock(A,java.nio.channels.CompletionHandler))
- [AsynchronousFileChannel#read(ByteBuffer, long, A, CompletionHandler)](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/channels/AsynchronousFileChannel.html#read(java.nio.ByteBuffer,long,A,java.nio.channels.CompletionHandler))
- [AsynchronousFileChannel#write(ByteBuffer, long, A, CompletionHandler)](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/channels/AsynchronousFileChannel.html#write(java.nio.ByteBuffer,long,A,java.nio.channels.CompletionHandler))
- [AsynchronousSocketChannel#connect(SocketAddress, A, CompletionHandler)](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/channels/AsynchronousSocketChannel.html#connect(java.net.SocketAddress,A,java.nio.channels.CompletionHandler))
- [AsynchronousServerSocketChannel#accept(A, CompletionHandler)](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/channels/AsynchronousServerSocketChannel.html#accept(A,java.nio.channels.CompletionHandler))

As you can see, all those methods (and others not listed) use the provided [CompletionHandler](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/channels/CompletionHandler.html) to notify callers of completion, whether the operation succeeded or failed. Most, if not all, of those methods have an overload which does not accept a `CompletionHandler` but instead returns a `Future`.

There's also [java.util.concurrent.CompletionStage](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/CompletionStage.html), which has many methods which invoke some functional interface implementation once the stage is complete.

Answer (score 1):

The Java standard library generally uses the `Future` abstraction instead of a callback as the core building block. If you want to build a "callback-based" structure, you then use the `then*` methods on `CompletionStage` (typically `CompletableFuture`).

This structure allows for flexibility in how the caller wants asynchronous results handled; for example, I've used it for scatter-gather on multiple downstream API calls used to build a compound result.

Comment: Thanks! Can you give an example?

Comment: @EllenSpertus The "then" methods _are_ the example. You say `asyncResult.thenAccept(callback)` (or whichever `then`, as you can chain them arbitrarily).

Answer (score 1):

Check https://github.com/javasync/idioms. You may find here different approaches of using asynchronicity with non-blocking IO with an example of counting the total number of lines of given files (e.g. `countLines(String...paths)`) using the following idioms:

- [Callbacks](https://github.com/javasync/idioms/blob/master/src/main/java/org/javasync/idioms/files/AsyncIoCallbacks3.java)
- [CompletableFuture](https://github.com/javasync/idioms/blob/master/src/main/java/org/javasync/idioms/files/AsyncIoCf3.java)
- [Reactive Streams](https://github.com/javasync/idioms/blob/master/src/main/java/org/javasync/idioms/files/AsyncIoRx.java)